# Comparing values in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, comparison

I have a reference dataframe called `ref` that looks like that:

```
ref = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','b','c','d'],
                  'col2':[100,100,100,300],
                  'col3':[200,200,500,400],
                  'col4':[300,np.NaN,600,600],
                  'col5':[400,np.NaN, 700,700]})

        col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
    0     a     100     200     300     400
    1     b     100     200     NaN     NaN
    2     c     100     500     600     700
    3     d     300     400     600     700
```

And I have another dataframe called `df` that looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col2':[105,100,100,200,300],
                  'col3':[202,200,200,300,391],
                  'col4':[300,np.NaN,350,400,605],
                  'col5':[398,np.NaN, 450,500,701]})

    col2    col3    col4    col5
0   105     202     300     398
1   100     200     NaN     NaN
2   100     200     350     450
3   200     300     400     500
4   300     391     605     701
```

What I am trying to do is to compare each row of `df` with the rows of `ref` in order to determine if they correspond to `a, b, c, d` or `None`. And because the values in `df` can be slightly different than the ones in `ref` , I would like to allow some 'error' so that if the difference between two values is not greater than 10, we allow a match.

In the end, I would like to obtain something like:

```
    col2    col3    col4    col5   id
0   105     202     300     398    a
1   100     200     NaN     NaN    b
2   100     200     350     450    none
3   200     300     400     500    none
4   300     391     605     701    d
```

The way I see it, the idea is to start with values in `df['col2']`, verify if it matches with any rows in `ref['col2']` and, for the ones where it matches, verify if `df['col3']` also match with `ref['col3']`and so on and so on. And once we identified (or not) the only row matching in `ref`, return the identifier written in `ref['col1]`.

I would need to have something "efficient" if possible, as my original dataset can have up to 135 columns. But I assume, as I stop focusing on rows in `ref` that doesn't match, it becomes easier to work on the ones that are left ?

I just started coding in python and using pandas on my own and I admit I am a bit lost. I'm not necessarily asking for the final code but could anyone send me in the good direction ?

I started coding this:

```
for read in df.itertuples():
    for ref in ref.itertuples():
        if abs(read[1]-ref[2]) <= 10:
            print(str(read[0])+' match '+str(ref[1]))
        else:
            print(str(read[0])+' match None')
```

But I didn't go very far..
First, I don't know how to "lock" the rows matching, so that I'm able to work exclusively on them for further comparisons.
Seconds, it returns "none" for every rows not matching, instead of only returning one line if none matches (which I assume is because I am using `itertuples()` )

Thanks for reading all this and thanks in advance for any tips !

**Edit:**

Here's the piece of code I have right now. I'm using `np.isclose()` for comparisons with a tolerance. but I'm sure there's a way to avoid writing each 'if' conditions for each comparisons.. (especially with 135 columns in my final DataFrame)

```
for read in df.itertuples():
    for ref in df2.itertuples():
        if np.isclose(read[1],ref[2],atol=10, equal_nan=True) == True:
            if np.isclose(read[2],ref[3],atol=10, equal_nan=True) == True:
                if np.isclose(read[3],ref[4],atol=10, equal_nan=True) == True:
                    if np.isclose(read[4],ref[5],atol=10, equal_nan=True) == True:
                        print(str(read[0])+' match '+str(ref[1]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way easy to set up with only 5 columns, not sure for up to 135 but it might give you an idea.

First replace the `NaN` by 0 (or any value far from all the values you have), then create two columns "sup" and "inf" for each `colX` depending on your error criteria in ref:

```
df = df.fillna(0)
ref = ref.fillna(0)
for nb in range(2,6):
    ref['col' + str(nb) + 'sup'] = ref['col' + str(nb)] + 10
    ref['col' + str(nb) + 'inf'] = ref['col' + str(nb)]  -10
```

Now define a function `find_match` to apply on each row of `df` which will select the row of `ref` matching:

```
def find_match ( row, ref):    
        row_ref = ref[(ref['col2sup'] >= row['col2']) & (ref['col2inf'] <= row['col2']) &
                      (ref['col3sup'] >= row['col3']) & (ref['col3inf'] <= row['col3']) &
                      (ref['col4sup'] >= row['col4']) & (ref['col4inf'] <= row['col4']) &
                      (ref['col5sup'] >= row['col5']) & (ref['col5inf'] <= row['col5'])]
        if not row_ref.empty:
            return row_ref['col1'].values[0]
        else:
            return None
```

Here it might be difficult to generalize to 135 columns.

Now you can create your column `id` in `df` with:

```
df['id'] = df.apply(find_match, args=([ref]),axis=1)
```

and you have your expected output

**EDIT:** to go up to N columns, you can replace in `find_match` the line `row_ref` by:

```
row_ref =  ref.copy()
for i in range(2,6):
    row_ref = row_ref[(ref['col'+str(i)+'sup'] >= row['col'+str(i)]) &
                      (ref['col'+str(i)+'inf'] <= row['col'+str(i)])]
```

and change the 6 to 136 for example. But I'm not sure about the efficiency of this method on large data.

**EDIT2:** so with `np.isclose`, you can do something like:

```
# definition of the function, change the 4 to the right number
def find_match ( row, df_ref):
    ser = df_ref[pd.np.isclose(row.iloc[:4], df_ref.iloc[:,1:], atol=0.1).all(axis=1)]['col1']
    if not ser.empty:
        return ser.values[0]
    else:
        return None
# and then apply
df['id'] = df.apply(find_match , args=([ref]),axis=1)
```

**EDIT3:** to not compare all the row if `Nan`:

```
def find_match ( row, df_ref):
    col_nan = row[row.isnull()].index
    if not col_nan.empty:
        ind_col = row.index.get_loc(col_nan[0])+1
    else:
        ind_col = 4 # number of column to compare if no nan in the row
    ser = df_ref[pd.np.isclose(row.iloc[:ind_col], df_ref.iloc[:,1:ind_col+1], atol=10, equal_nan=True).all(axis=1)]['col1']
    if not ser.empty:
        return ser.values[0]
    else:
        return None
```

Note: you may find another way to get the `ind_col` but this should work. Let me know if it's really faster (it depends on how much rows have `nan` and how many I guess).

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks for your time. Instead of creating two columns like you did, I decided to use np.isclose which allows to specify a tolerance (see my edit) but I'm stuck with the numbers of lines I have to write (one for each comparisons.. 135 seems a lot).

Comment: @FlorianBernard Your EDIT is a really good idea, actually, you find yourself the solution, you can pass arrays to `np.isclose()` so in your two loops `for`, you just need one `if` statement such as: `if np.isclose(read[1:5],ref[2:6],atol=10, equal_nan=True).all() == True:` that you can easily extend to 135 columns :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know I could write it like that .. I was really struggling to find a solution on how to avoid writing so many lines and the solution seem SO easy ! Now that I have a simple way to do the comparisons, I just need to create the id column. Can I use your method, put the above code into a function and then do df.apply(function) ?

Comment: @FlorianBernard yes you can, see my EDIT2 it should do it

Comment: I'm trying to improve the speed of the comparisons, would you know if it's possible to totally ignore the np.NaN values ? I think it would be faster if I don't perform the comparison on the next 125 columns when only the first columns are filled with 'actual' values .. just a thought !

Comment: @FlorianBernard what you want is to not perform the comparison if `col2` of your df has `np.Nan`? just talk about this column? and in your output you want to keep these lines or you don't mind as the `id` will be `None`?

Comment: I don't want to discard the row, just 'stop' the comparisons if the next value is NaN (because all the following values will be NaN as well so if it matched so far, it will match until the end) and then report the id. Hence, reducing the total amount of comparisons.

Comment: @FlorianBernard ok I understand. There is a way in `find_match` to find the column index of the first `np.nan` in the row and do the comparison on only the slice with actual values and the first np.nan (included). Not sure it will be faster but worth a try

Comment: @FlorianBernard see the EDIT3

Comment: It seems to be performing faster on that small dataset here (8.11µs versus 10µs) so that should be faster on bigger dataset as well I suppose ! thanks :)